# Diagonalization for sums of Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hermitian

I found an interesting question about diagonalizable matrices,

Let $A,B\in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ Hermitian, such that $AB\neq BA$.

Do there exist complex numbers $u\neq v$, such that $A+uB$ and $A+vB$ are not diagonalizable ?

It seems to be a consequence of  [Motzkin-Taussky theorem](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0024379581902238/1-s2.0-0024379581902238-main.pdf?_tid=1ffc2046-cb9a-11e3-9ea3-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1398335037_c4591fdbb29ee6eb7f7f06c9783b1a68) , which is difficult to prove, perhaps one can prove it directly without Motzkin-Taussky theorem  ?

Answer (score 2):

The following is a sketch of the proof.

A pair of complex matrices $(A,B)$ has property L if there exist orderings of the eigenvalues $(\lambda_i)$ and $(\mu_i)$ of $A$ and $B$ s.t., for all complex $(x,y)$, $spectrum(xA+yB)=(x\lambda_i+y\mu_i)$. According to the proof of Theorem 3 in "Pairs of matrices with property L. II " (Motzkin and Taussky): if $\lambda A+\mu B$ is a pencil in which all matrices, except possibly one, are diagonalizable, then $(A,B)$ has property L.

According to Theorem 2 in "Pairs of matrices with property L." (Motzkin and Taussky): if $A,B$ are hermitian and have property L, then $AB=BA$.

Here $AB\not= BA$ ; thus $(A,B)$ has not property L and the associated pencil contains at least $2$ non-diagonalizable matrices.

Comment: Loup blanc , Can you copy your answer on MSE here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820784/diagonalizable-over-mathbbc-implies-commuting. It will be great for MSE community. Thank you in advance.